# Party log register problem

Tags: c

there was a party.there was a log register in which entry and exit time of all the guests was logged.you have to tell the time at which there was maximum guest in the party.
input will be the entry and exit time of all the n guests [1,4] [2,5] [9,12] [5,9] [5,12]
the output will be t=5 as there was maximum 3 guest were there namly guest(starting from 1) 2,4 and 5.

what i tried so far is

```
main()
        {
    int ret;
    int a[5]={1,2,9,5,5};
    int b[5]={4,6,12,9,12};
    int i,j;
    int runs=5;
    int cur = 0,p1 = 0,p2 = 0;
    printf("input is ");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("(");
        printf("%d,%d",a[i],b[i]);
        printf(")");

    }

    while(runs--)
    {
        while(p1<5 && p2<5)
        {
            if(a[p1] <= b[p2])
            {
                cur ++;
                p1 ++ ;
            }
            else {
                cur --;
                p2 ++ ;
            }
            ret = cur ;
        }
    }
    printf("\n the output is %d",ret);

        }
```

i am getting 3 as output..which is completely wrong! where am i making error?

Comment: Just my 2c on your coding style. Avoid using magic numbers like 5. For ex, you can define a macro like `#define N_ELEMENTS(a) sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` and use it instead. Or even simply declare a const for the array size and use it.

Comment: This is same as finding the largest subarray in a given array of integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things are problematic with your code. Here's a few pointers on where to improve it:

- Your algorithm itself is doubtful. Assume that your first guest is the party host and stays from 1 until the end time of the party. With your current code, `p2` will never change and you will ignore all other guests' leave times.
- Even if your algorithm worked, it would assume that your input is sorted. By iterating `p1`/`p2` you implicitly assume growing times in your array, which is already wrong for your sample input. So you ought to sort the input first.
- You are assigning the result `ret` at each iteration of your main loop. This neglects the fact on whether the current state (`cur`) is the maximum number of guests or not. Hint: If yo are to compute a maximum of something and don't have any maximum computation in your code, there may be something missing.

Here's a different idea: Assuming you can spare an array of size maxtime, create an array filled with 0s. Process your input by increment the array at a certain time, if a guest arrives, and decrement it when a guest leaves. For example, the first 5 minutes would then look like `[1, 1, 0, -1, 1, ...]`. Then it's much simpler to walk linearly through the array and compute the maximum prefix sum. It's also much easier this way to compute the full time-interval for how long this maximum number of guests was present.

(If you want to go more fancy and have a much larger total time interval to cover, instead rely on a map with times as keys. Initialize like the array, then process the keys in sorted order.)

Comment: Another point (I dont think its worth an answer so I attach it here): He should use defines/consts for the 5 - so he could easily change the array size and the algorithm would still work, without patching the magic 5 everywhere in the code.

Comment: Keeping an array full of zeros is a huge waste of space. Have an array of pairs that look like (+1, arrival-time) and (-1, departure-time) instead, and sort it, comparing times.

Comment: That's basically what the map comment I gave does. It's not much difference if you use a sorted map with key-value thinking or explicit pairs with explicit sorting.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing an index instead of the actual time. Try printing **edited** <strike>`p1[ret]`</strike> `a[ret]`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, p1 is also an index. I actually mean `a[ret]`.